# Solution For Access Text-Box id and Method in one user control to anther user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a solution for access text-box id and method from A user control to B user control.

For example:

- User control A having text-box and method;
- User control B need to access text-box id in some method  as well as user control need to access A control Method?..

**First User Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UC_Documents.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_UC_Documents" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_ContractSummary" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMain_Folder" ReadOnly="true" Text="Attachment" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-lg-12"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>


public partial class ParentChildTreeView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void treeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //UserControl textboox = FindControl("UC_Documents") as UserControl; 
        //TextBox txtMain_Folder = (textboox.FindControl("txtMain_Folder") as TextBox); 
    }
}
```

how to access first user cotrol Textbox in ParentChildTreeView user control -> treeView_SelectedNodeChanged event?

Comment: Please provide acode/

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UC_Documents.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_UC_Documents" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_ContractSummary" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>                                                                                                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMain_Folder" ReadOnly="true" Text="Attachment" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-lg-12"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: this is first user control

Comment: public partial class ParentChildTreeView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {                                                                                                         protected void treeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //UserControl textboox = FindControl("UC_Documents") as UserControl;
            //TextBox txtMain_Folder = (textboox.FindControl("txtMain_Folder") as TextBox);                             }                                                                                                                       }

Comment: how to access first user cotrol Textbox in ParentChildTreeView user control -> treeView_SelectedNodeChanged event?..

Comment: please put this in your question itself @Ethiraj

Comment: okay but there is not accept this code for some format

Comment: I did that for you that will be applied soon.

Answer (score 0):

If the ParentChildTreeView has UC_Documents then,
change the access modifier of the Text-box to public, you would be able to access the text box through UC_Documents object.

Or create one public method in UC_Documents which returns value of the text box. Then access it from the ParentChildTreeView through UC_Documents object.

Comment: need that text-box id for assign --> txtMain_Folder.Text = treeView.SelectedNode.Text  in treeView_SelectedNodeChanged event selected Text Name

Comment: these two user control don't have relationships so need call directly

Comment: Are these usercontrols belongs to same web page?

Comment: yes these two user control belongs to same web page itself, but when i fire the 2nd user control node change event then i need to assign 1st user control text box

Comment: then set the value in the web page using the usercontrol objects

Comment: but i am using session to pass from user control to page but there is first time user control load then second time click on tree view means then only web page method fired so that's why,i need to call directly that textbox id